# Get URL of a route that has a subdomain constraint in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

So I have a route with a subdomain constraint:

```
match '/', :to => "static#home", :constraints => { :subdomain => "home" }, :as => "home"
```

But if I grab the path in my view...

```
<%= link_to home_url %>
```

It only gives me the part after the domain, it doesn't include the absolute path and the subdomain:

```
<a href="/"></a>
```

How can I grab `home_path` and still get the subdomain with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to add

`, :subdomain => "home"`

to the end of my route. I kept seeing that and thinking I had already done it with the constraint, but that was not the case. It needs the constraint and the subdomain defenition.